# Is this integral increasing?

Tags: integration, convolution, monotone-functions

I have a function $f(t)$ decreasing and a function $g(t)$ nonnegative.

I know for grant that $\int_0^t f(t-\theta)g(\theta)d\theta$ is increasing (I mean, this is part of hypothesys).

Now, I have $h(t)=f(t)k(t)$ where both $f(t) $ and $k(t)$ are decreasing, but $k(t)>1$.

I could say that is $\int_0^t h(t-\theta)g(\theta)d\theta$ increasing?

I know that $\int_0^t h(t-\theta)g(\theta)d\theta>\int_0^t f(t-\theta)g(\theta)d\theta$, but how can I prove that there is not oscilation?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

It's not true. Here is a counterexample. Let $f(t)=g(t)=e^{-t}$, and $k(t)=1+e^{-t}$. Then $f$ is decreasing, $g$ is non-negative, $k$ is decreasing, and $k>1$. Then,

$$\int_0^t f(t-\theta)g(\theta)d\theta =\int_0^t e^{-t+\theta}e^{-\theta}d\theta = te^{-t} $$

and

$$\int_0^t h(t-\theta)g(\theta)d\theta =\int_0^t (1+e^{-t+\theta})e^{-t+\theta}e^{-\theta}d\theta $$
$$ = \int_0^t (e^{-t}+e^{-2t+\theta}) d\theta $$
$$ = te^{-t} + e^{-2t} \int_0^t e^{\theta} d\theta $$
$$ = te^{-t} + e^{-2t} (e^t-1) $$
$$ = (t+1)e^{-t}-e^{-2t} $$
The derivative wrt $t$ is
$$ \frac{d}{dt} \int_0^t h(t-\theta)g(\theta)d\theta = 2e^{-2t}-te^{-t} $$
Then
$$ 2e^{-2t}-te^{-t}=0  \iff te^{t}=2 $$
We have that $\int_0^t h(t-\theta)g(\theta)d\theta$ is increasing for $0<t<W(2)$ and decreasing for $t>W(2)$, where $W$ is the Lambert W-function and $W(2)\approx 0.853...$

Comment: Thank you so much! But $\int_0^t f(t-\theta)g(\theta)d\theta$ is increasing as I was asking...? Sorry if I am confused! Maybe it seems that I afirmed this with basis on hypothesys, but not, in fact I have it for grant. Thank you!

Comment: @Quiet_waters No, the integral you mentioned is $te^{-t}$ in my example, which is nonmonotone. It has a turning point at $t=1$. You maybe need stronger conditions on $f$.

Comment: Thank you. I know the $\int_0^t f(t-\theta)g(\theta)d\theta$ by thypothesis, does it help? Thank you